# How do I find the time difference in hours minutes,, and seconds C# windows form app

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a program for my school, and I want it to say how long until the current period ends. I have found how to find what period it currently is, but unsure of how to get the basic hours, minutes, and seconds.

In my past attempts I got a number like 14.234534 and, I need a number so I can put it into basic hours, minutes and seconds.

I have this already and it is what gave me the 14.25341

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
double diffHours = 24 - (now - now.Date).TotalHours + 8;
string final = diffHours.ToString();
label11.Text = final;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't really tell from your description what "the current period ends" time is.  If you can express that as a `DateTime`, then you can get a `TimeSpan` by subtracting a `DateTime` from another `DateTime`.  For example, it's just after 6:30 pm local time here, so if I can calculate the time left until midnight like this:

```
var tonightAtMidnight = DateTime.Today + TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
TimeSpan timeLeftUntilMidnight = tonightAtMidnight - DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine(timeLeftUntilMidnight.ToString("g"));
```

I get this on my console:

> 5:30:23.1215299

If you lookup `TimeSpan.ToString(string)` you can see how to format that anyway you want.

### Update

Consider some code that looks like this:

```
private static readonly DateTime[] periodEndings = new DateTime[] {
        DateTime.Today + new TimeSpan (8, 40, 0),
        DateTime.Today + new TimeSpan (9, 20, 0),
        DateTime.Today + new TimeSpan (10, 0, 0),
        DateTime.Today + new TimeSpan (10, 40, 0),
        DateTime.Today + new TimeSpan (11, 20, 0),
        DateTime.Today + new TimeSpan (12, 0, 0),
        DateTime.Today + new TimeSpan (12, 40, 0),
        DateTime.Today + new TimeSpan (13, 20, 0),
        DateTime.Today + new TimeSpan (14, 0, 0),
        DateTime.Today + new TimeSpan (14, 40, 0),
        DateTime.Today + new TimeSpan (15, 20, 0),
        DateTime.Today + new TimeSpan (16, 0, 0),
    };

static string CalculateTimeToNextPeriod(DateTime now) {
    if (now < periodEndings[0]) {
        return "School hasn't started";
    };

    for (var i = 1; i < periodEndings.Length; ++i) {
        if (now > periodEndings[i - 1] && now < periodEndings[i]) {
            var timeLeft = periodEndings[i] - now;
            return timeLeft.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
        }

    }
    //otherwise
    return "School's over for the day";
}
```

The static array sets the time periods, and the little function returns a string that contains the hours/min/sec left from some time until the end of the period that ends after that time.  I really don't know what you are trying to do, but this should give you some ideas.

Comment: How do I make this to instead of midnight it is like 9:20 AM, or anything, It will not let me use "TimeSpan(10, 43, 0)" as a method, and I can't figure out another way, and aslo is there a way I can make this update every second to have a basic clock sort of thing?

Comment: If you want a DateTime to be at 9:20am today, you can use a `DateTime` constructor, or something like `var currentPeriodEnd = DateTime.Today + new TimeSpan(9, 20, 0);`.  The documentation for this stuff is really good, you should try it out.  A `DateTime` represents a point in time, while a `TimeSpan` represents a length of time (like between two `DateTime`).  Time and data math usually end up involving the two of them.

Comment: Yes.  But you need to get code that runs periodically.  How you'd do that depends on the environment you are running in (a web page, a Windows Forms app, etc.).  Basically, the idea is to have some sort or timer-ish event generator, and, then on the events, redo the calculation.  That would be another question, though.  Try to figure things out from my hints, write some code, and if you can't get it to work, ask it.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than going back and forth between `int`, `double`, and `DateTime` values, lets keep everything in terms of the [`TimeSpan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=netframework-4.7.2) type:

```
var Day = new TimeSpan(24, 0, 0);
var result = Day.Subtract(Date.Now - DateTime.Today).AddHours(8);
label11.Text = result.ToString();
```

There are also a number of [format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2) you can use to tweak the output.

Comment: It errors for me, in the second line where it says "date.now" it says it does not exist in the current context, not sure how to fix that either..